# How to pass a parameter in a SQL query in MS SQL Server from an Excel sheet

Tags: sql-server, excel, microsoft-query

Let's say I have this query in SQL Server:

```
select * 
from Table1 
where Column1 IN ('01061120192T')
```

I want to pass the values for `Column1` from a column in an Excel sheet.

I'm able to pass a single value to the query as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/197453/run-an-sql-query-with-a-parameter-from-excel-2007). But parenthesis of IN can accept multiple values so I want to pass 1000 values in the parenthesis from a column in an Excel sheet.

Tried to pass multiple values to the parameter as below, but that's not working.

```
=Sheet1!$G$1:$G$5
```

[image]

Comment: one way of achieving this, is to load the excel sheet into a table. Either using the SSMS import wizard or SSIS. Then change your query like below:                                           
select * 
from Table1 
where Column1 IN (Select ColumnName from TableName)

Comment: I guess this will create a new table on the server, every time I run the query.

Answer (score 0):

You pass variables in SSIS as a ?, and then define your variables in your parameter mapping pane.

```
select * 
from Table1 
where Column1 = ?
```

Then, you need to go to your Parameter mapping pane and click Add. Select your variable's name in the Variable name Column. Then Input as the direction.  Leave Paramter Size as -1.